Why is my Search in my Input not working properly?
I'm having trouble making a search input on my app, the deal is that when I search for instance
'Rosa' works fine, but when I write a mistake 'Roso', erase 'Ros' doesn't seems to work, not even if I write it properly 'Rosa'.
My app needs to work offline so that's why I'm using a local search.
I'm working with ISAR DB and onChanged Function
                onChanged: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    clientNotifier.refresh();
                    isSearching = false;
                  }
                  clientNotifier.search(value);
                  isSearching = true;
                  setState(() {});
                },

and using my function search this way
 void search(String query) {
    final tempClientsMap = <int, Client>{};
    manualDebounce();
    if (state.values.isEmpty) return;
    print('query: $query');
    for (final client in state.values) {
      if (client.nombreCliente.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())) {
        print('1 ${client.nombreCliente}');
        tempClientsMap[client.idCliente] = client;
      }
      if (client.idCliente.toString().contains(query)) {
        print('2 ${client.nombreCliente}');

        tempClientsMap[client.idCliente] = client;
      }
    }
    state = tempClientsMap;
  }

  manualDebounce() {
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      state = state;
    });
  }


Update
I tried to remove the manualDebounce, but I noticed that what erases my data is the final part state = tempClientsMap; because my temp has 0 results when wrong or incorrect my state stays in 0.
Does anyone know a better way or alternative to do a local search?


What's the clientNotifier? Is this a ValueNotifier? Why don't you use a ValueListenableBuilder instead using setState

My clientNotifier
final clientsState = ref.watch(localClientsProvider).values.toList();
final clientNotifier = ref.read(localClientsProvider.notifier);
Can you explain or expand ValueListenableBuilder approach?

This is because of the delay introduced by manualDebounce() function which waits for 500 milliseconds before updating the state. This debounce mechanism is typically used to reduce the frequency of updates, but it's causing an issue when the user quickly modifies the search query.
To fix this issue, you can remove the debounce mechanism and directly update the state inside the search function.

Hello I tried to remove the manualDebounce, but I noticed that what erases my data is the final part  state = tempClientsMap; because my temp has 0 results when wrong or incorrect my state stays in 0. Do you know a better way to do a local search?
